# Question about if accounts with NFTs and no Sol - will they be purged and NFT lost?

Tags: account

In this article in the beginning it explains that accounts with Sol will be purged. If there is an account that has 0 Sol but has an NFT in the account, will it be purged and if so what happens to the NFT in the account?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: No.

Not sure what article you are referring to.

NFTs are stored in [Associated Token Accounts](https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account), not directly in your wallet account.

Accounts are only purged if they are not '[rent-exempt](https://docs.solana.com/developing/intro/rent)'. All token accounts are automatically set up in a rent-exempt fashion, which is why there are small chain fees to mint.

(At some point I believe that accounts in general will not be allowed to enter a non-rent-exempt state - you either leave a tiny minimum balance, or completely close the account).

It is not required for the account owning a token account to have any Sol (though it will need to have some to pay for the fraction of a cent of gas should that account want to *do* anything with that token, unless they invoke a smart contract that pays for the fees itself. I believe Magic Eden might have such a contract for listing, e.g.).